# JOIN returns no rows and LEFT JOIN returns all values as null

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm pretty new to SQL and mostly dealt with databases involved in logins, basic data.

I'm trying to join 2 tables and am having trouble.

I have 2 tables, one is a complete list of all UK `lsoa` numbers and info on postcode called `postcode`, and a secondary table that contains information about the deprivation index of an area which also contains the `lsoa` number called `depriv`.

I'm trying to join these tables via the `lsoa` which is a `VARCHAR` with a format like: `E01000005`

My SQL is:

```
SELECT a.lsoa11, b.decile FROM postcode a
JOIN depriv b ON a.lsoa11=b.lsoa
```

This returns nothing, empty table

but:

```
SELECT a.lsoa11, b.decile FROM postcode a
LEFT JOIN depriv b ON a.lsoa11=b.lsoa
```

Returns the `lsoa11` table column correctly but the `decile` column is just `(NULL)`

What am I doing wrong?

```
SQL
|
|-postcode
|   |-lsoa11 { 'E01000001'; 'E01000002'; 'E01000003' }
|   |-pcd { 'EH1 1GF'; 'EH1 1GP'; 'EH1 5GP' }
|-depriv
|   |-lsao { 'E01000001'; 'E01000002'; 'E01000003' }
|   |-rank { '24,004'; '24,201'; '12,102' }
```

Comment: it would look like there's no data that matches the join condition?

Comment: @TZHX both tables contain the LSAO numbers and both have the same values unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: If your logic is correct both queries  will return result sets If they don't your logic is incorrect but since we can't see your data we can't say more.

Comment: Some sample data would be beneficial here. Have you checked your data does not have things like spaces or other hidden characters

Comment: It sounds like maybe your data isn't what you think it is. Try the queries `SELECT TOP 100 a.lsoa11 FROM postcode a ORDER BY lsoa11` and `SELECT TOP 100 b.lsoa FROM depriv b ORDER BY b.lsoa` and make sure the numbers are (mostly) matching. Note if they differ in upper/lower case you may ned to set a collation to get them to match

Comment: @Robert Sheahan mysql equivalent of top is limit, but syntax is different.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your problem [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: @RobertSheahan I've tried the first one you mentioned `SELECT a.lsoa11 FROM postcode a ORDER BY lsoa11 LIMIT 100` but it returns an empty column I'm guessing this is the issue?

Comment: @RobertSheahan If I remove the `LIMIT 100` it returns 2,656,000 rows but large amount of empty entries at the top which I'm guessing is what's being returned with `LIMIT 100`

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: You can edit the title the same way you can edit the body & tags: click on 'edit'.

Comment: [tour] This post like all site Q&A are here forever for others & you will be presumably further considering posting & posting. So the comment is to help you improve the post & avoid posting duplicate and/or unhelpful future question posts. (And even avoid answering similar posts.) This is both. Debug questions with no [mre] & duplicates should not be answered & merit closure  (having answers blocked) & unhelpful & unresearched questions merit downbotes & the problem here is an easily found duplicate answered many many times & with answers with thousands of votes. [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` means `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN` in MySQL.
It links data between one or more tables based on values of the common column between the tables.

`LEFT JOIN` selects all data starting from the left table.
For each row in the left table, it compares with every row in the right table and creating a corresponding new row.

Therefore, it can be inferred that `postcode` and `depriv` have no commons in `lsoa` which leads to such result.

Comment: I've remade the tables and now the statement works, hadn't split the data with `\n` so there was a lot of white space in the lsoa on `postcode` but it wasn't showing me looking at the data